# A word to define somebody that uses different objects not for their original use

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a word that is used to describe somebody that can build or fix things with objects that aren't used for that specific task.
Synonyms for this would be *resourceful* and *ingenious.*

Comment: What did you find when you looked *resourceful* up [in a thesarus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/resourceful)? What is there which you don't like and why? We need more data or this is just a guessing-game.

Comment: MacGyver: "Don't thank me, thank the Moon's gravitational pull!"

Comment: MacGyver is the answer, of course.

Answer (score 1):

**Improvise** means to produce or make [or repair] (something) from whatever is available.
"I improvised a costume for myself out of an old blue dress"
synonyms:   contrive, devise, throw together, cobble together, rig up ... [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/improvise)

The agent noun is **improvisor** and the adjective is **improvisorial**.

Comment: Oh man I had this question in my head for so long, thank you!

Comment: @Colin You mean you had this *answer* in the head?

Answer (score 0):

*Creative reuser:* An important concept in ecology and environment preservation.  See: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_reuse